# Java Hashmap: Swap two values?

Tags: java, hashmap, swap

Can I swap the keys of two values of a Hashmap, or do I need to do something clever?

Something that would look something like this:

```
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> prev = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: collection.entrySet()) {
        if (prev != null) {
            if (entry.isBefore(prev)) {
                entry.swapWith(prev)
            }
        }
        prev = entry;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort a bunch of items using a key? Just use a TreeMap instead and either provide a Comparator or override equals and compareTo.

Comment: This probably needs a little more explanation. What are the integer keys? Do they enforce some kind of order? If so and if you're sorting based on the String value, why not just use a List instead? Or does the key have some other meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you're just after a Map where the keys are ordered, use a [`SortedMap`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead.

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
```

You can rely on the natural ordering of the key (as in, its `Comparable` interface) or you can do custom ordering by passing a `Comparator`.

Alternatively you can call `setValue()` on the `Entry`.

```
Map.Entry<Integer, String> prev = null;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: collection.entrySet()) {
  if (prev != null) {
    if (entry.isBefore(prev)) {
      String current = entry.getValue();
      entry.setValue(prev.getValue();
      prev.setValue(current);
    }
  }
  prev = entry;
}
```

Personally I'd just go with a `SortedMap`.

Comment: I'm trying to sort the String values according to a specific algorithm.

Comment: Then write a comparable interface and pass it to the constructor for the map.  See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html and http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: Actually, if you're trying to sort the string values then what you want is a Map<String, Integer>.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like that in the `Map` or `Entry` interfaces but it's quite simple to implement:

```
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> prev = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: collection.entrySet()) {
            if (prev != null) {
                    if (entry.isBefore(prev)) {
                            swapValues(e, prev);
                    }
            }
            prev = entry;
    }

    private static <V> void swapValues(Map.Entry<?, V> first, Map.Entry<?, V> second)
    {
            first.setValue(second.setValue(first.getValue()));
    }
```